# PowerShell - piping enumerable objects

Tags: powershell

Specifically my example is with MSMQ queues. Consider the following:

```
Add-Type System.Messaging
[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachineName('.') | gm
```

What is *actually* piped out is the *messages* in the queue, not the `MessageQueue` objects themselves, as one might expect. I assume this is because `MessageQueue` is enumerable.

How can I force PowerShell to pipe the `MessageQueue` objects themselves and prevent it from enumerating them?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to force PowerShell to keep the array intact by prefixing a comma:

```
,[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachineName('.') | gm
```

Comment: This certainly works but it does so by putting the original array inside of a new array.  Then the pipeline unrolls the new array and a single item is sent down the pipeline. That single item being the original array.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `-InputObject` parameter on Get-Member as it will not unroll the object e.g.:

```
Get-Member -InputObject ([Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachineName('.'))
```

Yeah this is actually avoiding the pipeline altogether but it's a good technique to have in your bag of PowerShell tricks.